# .htaccess (or any other language code script) to limit to html page visits to a certain number for a set time?

Tags: javascript, php, apache, .htaccess, url

Can I use .htaccess file on my HTML website to block access to a random ip address user to a specific URL for a set amount of time (like 1 hour, 1 day, 1 month etc) after the same ip address has accessed the same URL for a set limited times in a set amount of time (like 5 times within 1 minute or 1 hour etc). Is it possible with .htaccess or do you need to use any other programming language to achieve this functionality (like pHp, Ruby, Javascript etc)?

Comment: By doing this you are potentially blocking users behind shared proxies that randomly route out the traffic from random ip addresses for outgoing load balancing reasons

Comment: You can do that in PHP with Database but They can spoof it easily..

Comment: `.htaccess` is not a programming language, is just a configuration file of the Apache web server. You can put pretty complex rules inside, for example the regular expressions used by `mod_rewrite`, but there are only rules and options. For what you want to do you need to use a programming language like the ones you mention.